# Calculate total time taken within grouping minus overlap in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table where start time and end time are timestamps and the interval could last a few days, and I'd like to compute the total time taken for each type of personnel grouped by ID and Task, discounting the overlap.

There's no guarantee that the tasks are completed in sequence.
Thanks so much for helping!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select task_group, person, id, count(ts) minutes 
from (
  select task_group, id, person, ts
  from data, unnest(generate_timestamp_array(start_time, timestamp_sub(end_time, interval 1 minute), interval 1 minute)) ts
  group by task_group, id, person, ts
  having count(1) = 1
)
group by task_group, id, person
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: hey, thanks for replying :) @Mikhail Berlyant I've posted my new question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68427108/calculate-total-time-within-grouping-in-sql