# Calculate total time within grouping

Tags: sql

I have a table (start time and end time are timestamps and the a single task could take a few days to complete), and I'd like to compute the total time taken for each type of personnel grouped by ID and task, counting the overlap.

Comment: What is the type of start and end time columns?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen They are both timestamps

Answer (score 1):

Consider yet another option

```
with temp1 as ( # original data falttened by minute 
  select task_group, id, person, ts
  from data, 
  unnest(generate_timestamp_array(start_time, timestamp_sub(end_time, interval 1 minute), interval 1 minute)) ts
  group by task_group, id, person, ts
), temp2 as ( # all minutes from min to max in original data 
  select task_group, id, ts
  from (
    select task_group, id, 
      min(start_time) over(partition by task_group, id) min_time,
      max(end_time) over(partition by task_group, id) max_time, 
    from data
  ), unnest(generate_timestamp_array(min_time, timestamp_sub(max_time, interval 1 minute), interval 1 minute)) ts
), temp3 as ( # matrix with Company, Customer, Both as columns by task_group, id as rows and minutes as values
  select task_group, id, Company, Customer, Both, count(ts) minutes 
  from (
    select task_group, id, t1.person, ts 
    from temp2 t2
    left join temp1 t1
    using(task_group, id, ts)
    group by task_group, id, person, ts
  )
  pivot (count(person) for person in ('Company', 'Customer', 'Both', null))
  group by task_group, id, Company, Customer, Both
)
select task_group, id, personnel, minutes from (
select task_group, id, 
  sum(if(Company = 1, minutes, 0)) Company,
  sum(if(Customer = 1, minutes, 0)) Customer,
  sum(if(Both = 1, minutes, 0)) Both,
  sum(if((Company,Customer) = (1, 1), minutes, 0)) overlap_cust_company,
  sum(if((Company,Both) = (1, 1), minutes, 0)) overlap_company_both,
  sum(if((Customer,Both) = (1, 1), minutes, 0)) overlap_cust_both,
  sum(if((Company,Customer,Both) = (1, 1, 1), minutes, 0)) overlap_across_all,
  sum(if((Company,Customer,Both) = (0, 0, 0), minutes, 0)) Doing_nothing
from temp3
group by task_group, id)
unpivot (minutes for personnel in (Company, Customer, Both, overlap_cust_company, overlap_company_both, overlap_cust_both, overlap_across_all, Doing_nothing))
```

If applied to sample data in your question  output is

[image]

Comment: for bigger tables, this method works better! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
with temp1 as (
  select task_group, id, person, ts
  from data, unnest(generate_timestamp_array(start_time, timestamp_sub(end_time, interval 1 minute), interval 1 minute)) ts
  group by task_group, id, person, ts
), temp2 as (
  select task_group, id, ts
  from (
    select task_group, id, 
      min(start_time) over(partition by task_group, id) min_time,
      max(end_time) over(partition by task_group, id) max_time,
    from data
  ), unnest(generate_timestamp_array(min_time, timestamp_sub(max_time, interval 1 minute), interval 1 minute)) ts
)
select task_group, id, 
  if(t1.person = t2.person, t1.person, format('overlap_%s_%s', t1.person, t2.person)) personnel,
  countif(t1.ts = t2.ts) minutes
from temp1 t1 left join temp1 t2
using(task_group, id) where t1.person <= t2.person
group by task_group, id, t1.person, t2.person
union all
select task_group, id, 'overlap_across_all' personnel, countif(flag) minutes,
from (
  select task_group, id, ts, 
    count(distinct person) over(partition by task_group, id, ts) = 3 flag 
  from temp1
)
group by task_group, id
union all
select task_group, id, 'Doing_nothing' personnel, count(ts) minutes
from (
  select distinct task_group, id, ts
  from temp2 t2 left join temp1 t1
  using (task_group, id, ts) where t1.ts is null
)
group by task_group, id
# order by personnel
```

If applied to sample data in y our question - output is

[image]